# converting this hierachy into xml? confused

Tags: xml, xsd

i havent really worked with xml before, but i was wondering how could turn this hierachy into an xml format, if that makes sense :)) thanks

```
agent
       agentname
       email
       allproperty
         aproperty
               postcode
               price
               imagefilename
               visits
        aproperty
               postcode
               price
               imagefilename
               visits
       aproperty
               postcode
               price
              imagefilename
              visits
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<agent>
   <agentname></agentname>
   <email></email>
   <allproperty>
      <aproperty>
           <postcode></postcode>
           <price></price>
           <imagefilename></imagefilename>
           <visits></visits>
      </aproperty>
      <aproperty>
           <postcode></postcode>
           <price></price>
           <imagefilename></imagefilename>
           <visits></visits>
      </aproperty>
      <aproperty>
           <postcode></postcode>
           <price></price>
           <imagefilename></imagefilename>
           <visits></visits>
      </aproperty>
  </allproperty>
</agent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do a thing like this?

```
<agent>
    <name>agentName</name>
    <email>agentEmail</email>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <postcode>myPostcode</postcode>
            ...
        </property>
        ...
    </properties>
</agent>
```